# How Can Change color of 10 Edit control by single function in c++ builder

Tags: c++, delphi, api, c++builder

i want to change color of edit control when enter edit and when exit from edit, i want do this by single function i dont want to add code for each edit in enter event or on exit event

Comment: You can subclass the edit control procedure and do it there. That's assuming you use the Windows API, as it's not really apparent.

Comment: you could also subclass the edit VCL component class.

Comment: `SetWindowLongPtr` with `GWLP_WNDPROC`.

Comment: iam new in c++ i want code for this idea

Comment: There are examples of subclassing everywhere.

Comment: (TObject *Sender) is useful or not!

Comment: Its really easy actually. set the same `OnEnter`/`OnExit` event handlers for all the Edit controls you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes like David and kobik said you just need to create event handlers for OnEnter and OnExit and assign the controls you wish to use them

for example

Add two TEdit's to your form and in the constructor of the form do the following

```
__fastcall TTestForm::TTestForm(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    Edit1->OnEnter = EditEnter;
    Edit2->OnEnter = EditEnter;

    Edit1->OnExit = EditExit;
    Edit2->OnExit = EditExit;
}
```

Now Create the Enter and Exit event handlers like so

```
void __fastcall TTestForm::EditEnter(TObject *Sender)
{
    TEdit *Temp = (TEdit*)Sender;
    Temp->Color = clRed;
}

void __fastcall TTestForm::EditExit(TObject *Sender)
{
    TEdit *Temp = (TEdit*)Sender;
    Temp->Color = clGreen;
}
```

Thats it.

Comment: You might consider using a `dynamic_cast` instead of the regular C-style cast. This will add some runtime type checking, and generally be more VCL'ish :)

Comment: Better to use a `static_cast` if you know the Sender will always be a `TEdit*`, as `dynamic_cast` has runtime overhead that `static_cast` does not.

Comment: Also, to add to Shaun's answer, you can assign the event handlers at design-time instead of in code at runtime.  The `OnEnter` and `OnExit` events are declared as `__published` and thus are accessible in the IDE's Object Inspector.

Answer (score 1):

Write OnEnter and OnExit event handlers and assign them to each control. Use the Sender parameter to the event to identify which control the event applies to.